# Passing Parameter to Angular2 Component

Tags: html, angular

I'm Learning Angular2 so be gentle... I have a basic Component which has a string array. I want to pass an integer to this component and have it return the string found at the index of that parameter.

E.g. myComponent[number]=1 returns string "second element".

My code so far is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template: 
    `<h1>Returned Value {{returnedString}}</h1>,`, 
  inputs:['number']
})
export class MyComponent  { 
  myStringArray: string[]; 
  returnedString: string;

  constructor(){
    this.myStringArray = ['First','Second','Third','Forth','Fifth','Sixth'];
    this.returnedString = 'number'+this.myStringArray['number'.valueOf()];
  }
}
```

I am calling this component as follows

```
<myComponent [number]=1></myComponent>
```

I print the value returned to the screen and get 'undefined'.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you want to bind to a custom property import Input and OnChanges from core and then implement as Input to create your custom property. The OnChanges just ensures your value gets updated when the bound value changes.

Remove the inputs key from your component decorator

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template: 
    `<h1>Returned Value {{returnedString}}</h1>,`
})
export class MyComponent  implements OnChanges { 
  myStringArray: string[];
  returnedString: string;
  @Input() inputNumber: number; 

  constructor(){
    this.myStringArray = ['First','Second','Third','Forth','Fifth','Sixth'];
    this.returnedString = 'number'+this.myStringArray[Number(this.inputNumber)];
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.returnedString = 'number'+this.myStringArray[Number(this.inputNumber)];   
  }
}
```

Update your code usage to the following

```
<myComponent [inputNumber]="1"></myComponent>
```

Here is a sample plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/S074zoVJ3ktQDKkcQgxe?p=preview

Comment: Thats it. So i needed the @Input() xxxx:number and the import at the top editied and then the ngOnChanges()....

Comment: Yes. In a more advanced case you might want to also implement `ngOnDestroy` incase you are creating large objects that need to be destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Apologies...that didnt work, sorry for jumping the gun there. Im still getting undefined

Comment: what are you using this line for `inputs:['number']`?

Comment: I thought this is how i brought the parameter in and init'd a var with it, tbh im not sure, i followed a tutorial that was doing something a little (not much) more complicated and they used this. Where do i retrieve the parameter value from?

Comment: Guys, the `OnChanges` interface is ONLY for your IDE and the compiler. Angular doesn't care if it's here or not. It's a way of saying to the IDE and TS compiler "this class must have an ngOnChanges method to be valid". You DO NOT have to write `implements OnChanges` or import the `OnChanges` for the code to work... If the `ngOnChanges()` exists, then Angular will call it. Full stop.

Comment: @Evans M ...I have the answer....I used your @Input() but inserted the param name into it...@Input('inputNumber') inputNumber: number. Amend your answer and i will mark as correct

Comment: rename the bound property to `inputNumber` see updated answer

Answer (score 6):

I had tough time to send string inputs. here is the correct way,

```
<myComponent [stringvar]="'string value'"></myComponent>
```

"string value" will not work. angular expecting object or number inside double quotes. string should be inside single quotes within double quotes "'string'"

Comment: Actually attributes between `[...]` are interpreted as JavaScript code, thus the need to use quotes. To pass simple strings one can use attributes directly. Your sample would be: `<myComponent stringvar="string value"></myComponent>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a number variable in your component too that will hold the value.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'myComponent',
  template: 
    `<h1>Returned Value {{returnedString}}</h1>,`, 
  inputs:['myNum']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit { 
  myStringArray: string[] = ['First','Second','Third','Forth','Fifth','Sixth']; 
  returnedString: string;
  public myNum: number;  <= here is your variable

  ngOnInit() {
      //you can use this.myNum anywhere now like this
      this.returnedString = 'number '+ this.myStringArray[this.myNum];
  }

  constructor(){

  }
}
```

You may have to change the name of your input because number is a `keyword`.

Another Note: You have to use `OnInit` instead of `constructor` to start using your inputs. `ngOnInit` is an `Angular2 lifecycle` method that is called by Angular when it's done building the component and evaluated the bindings

Comment: That was one of the issues. Other could be, you have to use ngOnInit, the value of input isn't yet available in the constructor. Give a try to updated answer now

Comment: still undefined. I had to put both the import {OnInit} from '@angular/core'; and the import { Component } from '@angular/core'; in as it failed with just the onInit

Comment: is it how i pass it from the calling class?

Comment: Try sending it like `<myComponent [myNum ]="1"></myComponent>`

Comment: Try to` console.log` `this.myNum` in your ngOnInt event, does it contains a nnumber?

Comment: @Fearghal Are you sure your code looks like above and still doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, iI had a diff var name in the calling class - 'number' and so it wasnt getting it. Thx for the help man.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative. It demonstrates how to use a getter for `returnedString`. Less code needed than with `ngOnChanges`.

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `
    <p>returnedString = {{ returnedString }}</p>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  myStringArray: string[]  = ['First','Second','Third','Forth','Fifth','Sixth'];
  @Input() stringIndex: number;

  get returnedString(): string {
    if (this.stringIndex !== undefined) {
      return this.myStringArray[this.stringIndex];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. **[See this demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdgtdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild.component.ts)**  Let's say you have two components `parent` and `child`. And you want to pass a variable to `child` and modify it there, say `views`.

On `parent` template:

`<child [(views)]="views"></child>`

On `child` component:

```
  @Input() views: number;
  @Output() viewsChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  // Bind this function to button click or some events:
  updateViews() {
    this.views++;
    this.viewsChange.emit(this.views); // Emit the value to parent:
  }
```

---

**Detail explanation:**
When you bind `[(views)]` in parent, it is acting as:

```
<child 
        [views]="views" 
        (viewsChange)="views = $event">
</child>
```

So, it is listening to `viewsChange` output function. Whenever, you do `viewsChange.emit`, the parent `views` get updated.

> Gotcha: The output function should be precisely named `$var + "Change"`. If you chose to name something else you will have to do:

```
<child 
            [views]="views" 
            (customEmitterFunction)="views = $event">
    </child>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass data from the child component to the father component you shuold set an Output parameter, to trigger  the signal  your component should implements the OnChanges interface, your component should be like this

```
    import { Component, Input,Output,EventEmitter,OnChanges,SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  template: `
    <p>returnedString = {{ returnedString }}</p>
  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  myStringArray: string[]  = ['First','Second','Third','Forth','Fifth','Sixth'];
  @Input() stringIndex: number;
 @Output() cardinalNumber:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();// you define an Output, this will emit a signal that will received from the father Component

  ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges) {
  // when the input changes we emit a signal
  this.cardinalNumber.emit(this.myStringArray[this.stringIndex]);
  }
  get returnedString(): string {
    if (this.stringIndex !== undefined) {
      return this.myStringArray[this.stringIndex];
    }
  }
}
```

then in the template of the father component you should insert :

```
    <my-cmp [stringIndex]=the parameter in father Component's controller
         (cardinalNumber)="method2beinvoked($event)">
</my-cmp>
```

method2beInvoked is the method in the father component that handles the message;
or you could do like this:

```
    <my-cmp [stringIndex]=the parameter in father Component's controller
         (cardinalNumber)="parameter=$event")>
</my-cmp
```

where parameter is a parameter in the father's component  controller