# not able to read @input property value in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating one component for reusing its code.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-jform',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './jform.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./jform.component.css']
})
export class JformComponent implements OnInit {

     @Input('init') modulename:string = '';

     ngOnInit() {
        this.getJsonForm();
        console.log(this.modulename); 
     }
}
```

inside another compenent's view file, I have this selector's use as follow,

```
<app-jform [modulename]="Blue32"></app-jform>
```

Now I am not able to get modulename as "Blue32" in console. I have already imported input module and I haven't get any other errors.

Update :as per the suggestion from  @SurenSrapyan I have changed the @Input declaration. Still Somehow not able to get it.

Now, I am getting "undefined" in console.

Comment: I think it is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41926598/passing-parameter-to-angular2-component , still checking solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your element is accessible from view via name `init`. If you will remove `'init'` part from the `@Input('init')`, it will be accessible via `modulename`.

Check this

```
@Input('init') modulename: string

<app-jform [init]="'Blue32'">
</app-jform>
```

or this

```
@Input() modulename: string

<app-jform [modulename]="'Blue32'">
</app-jform>
```

Comment: I tried changing to above syntax. But somehow its still not working. Am I really missing anything here?

Comment: You need to pass `Blue32` inside  string `'Blue32'`. I think you just need to pass that string, not a value of a variable `Blue32`

Comment: Yes I am passing only string value. Do you think that it is due to some lifecycle  conflict of  oninit() function and value of input variable at the time of printing?

Comment: Input Value is available at OnInit. Have you used like this `[init]="'Blue32'"`

Comment: Omg, It just worked. I dont know what was the problem.I have been trying from morning today and checked almost all the things. Thank you so much for the help.